# Understanding「。。。すべてのもう」

Tags: grammar, anime

From: No Game No Life ep.2 timestamp: 04:02

Context: Characters discuss bets before the game of rock-paper-scissors.

> …で 何を賭けるんですの？
>
> お前が勝ったらお前の要求をすべてのもう

Netflix translation: "If you win, we'll do anything you want".

It seems like there's a verb like する missing from the sentence, but then what role does すべてのもう play here and what does it mean, exactly? Without the の, すべて would be an adverb for する but in this case it's a noun instead, no?

Interestingly enough, even Google can't find this construction. Maybe it's supposed to be written in kanji?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sentence has an idiom, 要求を**飲む**, meaning "to accept one's demand". すべて is an adverb that modifies 飲む. See the fourth definition in [this entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%A3%B2%E3%82%80/). (BTW 要求をする does not make sense.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, as always :) Do you have any idea why it's written as のもう instead of のむ？

Comment: @LonelyDriver 飲もう is the volitional form of 飲む